# What is the norm of an element in $L^\infty(\mathbb{D})$ using the weak-star topology?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Under the convention that $L^1(\mathbb{D})$ has normalized Lebesgue measure for the unit disc in $\mathbb{C}$, its dual space can be regarded as $L^\infty(\mathbb{D})$. Hence we can equip $L^\infty(\mathbb{D})$ with a weak-star topology. I am trying to gain an elementary understanding of the weak-star topology, and am wondering what the norm is given by in this space.  Thank you.

Comment: The weak-star topology is not induced by a norm.

Comment: How unfortunate. What is the metric on the space?

Comment: There is no canonical metric, but [here is one of metrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem#Sequential_Banach.E2.80.93Alaoglu_theorem).